# Protecting conditional formatting of a cell or range

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I want that even if a user paste some data using (cntrl + V) or (right click + paste) , only values should be pasted, Conditional formatting should not be changed.

I tried this method https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1277-excel-protect-format.html

but it is protecting data validation only (drop down menu) but color fill formatting is changing if some data is pasted using ( <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> ) or (right click + paste).
if excel does not include this function suggest some VBA code .

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you want to hear, but protecting only the conditional formatting of cells - while allowing entering data - is virtually impossible.

Excel does not have this functionality built-in, so you would need code. But there are many different ways that cells can be overwritten -- i.e. keyboard shortcuts, ribbon commands, context menus, vba,  -- and while writing code to intercept these changes is not possible,  code to undo these changes is a very complex beast to write as well.

You may want to educate your users to paste values only.